# What can be the cause of java.net.SocketException: recv failed: Insufficient buffer space?

Tags: java, sockets

A customer receive the error "java.net.SocketException: recv failed: Insufficient buffer space" on windows. With the netstat command we see only approx. 100 socket connections. I have change the **MaxUserPort** to 60000 like described at http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;196271

I know that this Java error is equals to the socket error 10055 WSAENOBUFS. But I have no idea where I should search for the cause of this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: can you give more info on the environment and software?
Does your server rapidly open up connections? Is this a self created socket server or is it some kind of application server? Are you using java's nio packages?
Oh, and is this the server socket (listening)? or client socket connecting out?

Comment: What is a "problematic port number"? Could you enlighten me what did you mean by that?

Answer (score -1):

I know it has been some time (11 years), but I found a solution on that page: https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/WSAENOBUFS%3A+10055%3A+No+buffer+space+available

It is for SAP, however remedy is the same.

In short, it says: You are trying to reuse the same port after it is closed. This is probably your application extensively opens and closes the network connections. Remedy is to tweak with network parameters so that operation system shall release the closed ports faster.

I think it would be better to investigate why the application uses extensive amount of ports.

Comment: Your link doesn't make sense. The situation they describe would happen on bind or connect, not on receive, and it would priduce a bind error, not an out of buffer space error.